# Is 100g of wet food sufficient for 1 year old cats with different weights of course?

Tags: cats, diet

Do you think that 100g/day of wet food based on the following diet is enough? Taking into consideration that I feed them also dry food all day long.

My cats are 1 year old, they are sister and brother and they are fixed too.

- Joe is 5 kg (MALE)
- Moe is 3 kg (FEMALE)

**[Terra Faelis](http://www.wouafmiaou.com/terra-faelis-viande-poulet-1256.html) is composed of the following:**

- Crude protein 9.3%
- Crude fat 7.6%
- Crude fiber 0.4%
- Ashes 1%
- Humidity 81.4%
- Carbohydrates estimated 0.30%
- Protein dry mass 50.0%

In general it has the following ingredients

ingredients: chicken, squash & catmint: chicken hearts (32%), chicken muscle meat (20%), chicken stomachs (20%), chicken liver (15%), squash (5%), zucchini , watercress, rosehip powder, catmint (0.5%), organic eggshell powder (0.4%), whey, spirulina algae (0.3%), andean salt. proportions: 86.5% meat, 9.7% vegetables and herbs, 3.8% other ingredients. additives: nutritional additives: taurine (1000 mg / kg).

[image]

Comment: What is the calorie content of this food?

Comment: @AllisonC   RPC (Rapport protéines/calories) : between 80 et 120

Comment: Is that equivalent to kCal/g? Or is there a number available for kCal/g?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your cats have dry food available, reducing the amount of wet food is not a problem.

The wet food does look a little high in fat and low in fiber, but this is only my opinion, and it is not a problem. But I think you need to keep an eye on your cats' digestion, and if they get problems, you might have to change back to the other brand.

When free feeding dry food, be sure to have plenty of fresh water for your cats. I have found placing the water away from the food (in another room or behind a corner) makes cats drink more.

Comment: thank you trond. But a question. is it possible to ask you if u use a specific brand ? or maybe u feed them like home made food for cats?

Comment: i feed my cat purina dry food different taste(tuna or salmon) and for wet food i do not use a spesific brand,but as you know cats have strong opinions about what to eat and what not to eat so she want her food in gravy/gel.as treats i use raw meat(beef-pork-lamb-deer-whale meat)but i give this less than once a week,my cat do not like poultry of any type.my cat do roam free and hunt if she want to and she realy want to :)

Answer (score 1):

Feed your cat half a pouch 3-4 times with some kibble, don't pay any attention to people feeding their cats more than 3-4 pouches a day. I have two cats, medium to large. They get fat with more than two a day. Feeding actual meat is best, as kibble has zero health benefits other than MAYBE cleaning teeth. They need protein from meat, not from plants as it's meant to be from dry stuff, but even then, all of that protein is destroyed in the cooking process. Also, pet food is not regulated, so most commercial foods are not great for your cats health.

Comment: I would like to see a few references to the various claims you made (protein destroyed, meat being the best choice...).

Comment: Cats are obligate carnivores, which means that their digestive system is adapted to processing meats, not vegetables. Here's a link: https://www.aspca.org/news/why-cant-my-cat-be-vegan